# vscode: multiple extensions for one language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it specified somewhere what happens if I install multiple extensions that declare support for the same language? I can see that if the provided functionality doesn't overlap, then all is fine and I get everything. But if two extensions want to provide completion or hover info, for example, I'm not sure which one provides the answers or if they are merged (where applicable). Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any issues with multiple extension for the same thing, atm I am using a bunch for XML and while they tend to play nice together I've noticed that there are cases that if 1 crashes it might affect the others as well.

In my case a styling extensions was breaking from time to time and in turn my own extension was not getting called but it occurred relatively at random as some times this was not the case.

To me it appears that if - for example - there is an uncaught exception it happens